# How to generate a hierarchical list of all pages and child-pages using a regular query?

Tags: theme-development

I'm trying to query all the pages (just the title) to generate a ul/li-tree structure, using a regular query:

```
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><?php the_title(); ?></li> <?php
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Is it possible to detect the level of the current page/post, and whether it has a parent or not? I just want it to output something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Parent 1<ul>
        <li>Child 1-1</li>
        <li>Child 1-2</li>
    </ul></li>
    <li>Parent 2</li>
    <li>Parent 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_list_pages()` instead. Just pass your post type in if you're trying to list something other than Page-pages:

```
<ul>            
<?php wp_list_pages(array(
'post_type' => 'yourposttype',
'title_li' => ''
) ); ?>
</ul>
```

If you wanted to display this on all post types you could use

```
<ul>            
<?php wp_list_pages(array(
'post_type' => $post->post_type,
'title_li' => ''
) ); ?>
</ul>
```

which would automatically grab the post type of the currently viewed item and display the full tree for that post type.

Comment: This can work, thank you. Do you know of any way of adding different classes to the 1st and 2nd level of li-tags?

Comment: Its built-in functionality will include class "page_item_has_children" on any `<li>` that has children. Also built-in, `ul.children` for any child lists. You should be able to style based on that. If you really want to add your own classes, you'd need to use a custom walker.